# CAD model of the LEGO monorails

Tags: cad, monorail

I was wondering two things, Is it legal to share CAD models of LEGOs with other people as long as it is not for profit and Does anyone have A CAD model of the LEGO monorail track that was made in the late eighty's and early ninety's?

Answer (score 3):

First question;  yes. as long as they are your CAD models you can do that , for example on [Brickshelf](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/search.cgi?q=monorail%20cad&stype=fi)
Second question: In  [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/) , A CAD program for Lego they have monorail parts, [here](http://www.ldraw.org/cgi-bin/ptscan.cgi?q=mono)

this may also be usefull
[Monorail Network Planner Tool](http://sariel.pl/2011/05/monorail-network-planner-tool/)